# Best way to load videos - VideoCapture vs Frames

Tags: python, video, benchmarking, video-capture, opencv

I require loading a video for my project and I wanted to find fastest way to load videos. I am comparing cv2 VideoCapture vs loading frames of video (already preprocessed).

Here is code I wrote for benchmarking (which I believe is pretty much self explanatory):

```
import re
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer

vid = "some_video.avi"

natsort = lambda s: [int(t) if t.isdigit() else t.lower() for t in re.split('(\d+)', s)]

###############################################################################################################

start = timer()
for i in range(50):
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    vframes = []
    while success:
        vframes.append(image[None,:,:,:]) 
        success,image = vidcap.read()
    vframes = np.concatenate(vframes, 0)

end = timer()

print(end - start) ##### ==> 3.720745261060074
###############################################################################################################

start = timer()

for i in range(50):
    iframes = []
    listframes = glob.glob("*.jpg")
    listframes.sort(key=natsort)
    for frame in listframes:
        iframes.append(cv2.imread(frame)[None,:,:,:])
    iframes = np.concatenate(iframes, 0)

end = timer()

print(end - start) ##### ==> 7.264567195205018
###############################################################################################################
```

I found that videocapture (method-1) was quicker than loading frames sequentially. This seemed a little unintuitive to me since loading it has to do more work in breaking video into frames compared to second method. Can some explain the reason for this or if I am mistaken? Also please suggest any other efficient approach for video loading as well 
(The size of video is small, about 30-40 frames only)

EDIT : I have added the results in the code-window. As you can see almost double speedup is obtained!

Comment: video may use different copression which means less data to read. And it may use some hardware to decompress it. But is loading video much faster then loading images ? You didn't add results.

Comment: Video codecs are usually *very* well optimized, and the I/O cost of reading it as one big stream is lower than globbing and opening each image file separately, then parsing each image file's JPEG metadata.  Each `open()` + `read()` system call costs significant time (especially on modern x86 with Spectre + Meltdown mitigation enabled), and depending on the video codec it might not be much more expensive to decode than JPEG.  (Especially if the video decoder library is optimized with AVX2 and the JPEG decoder isn't.)